# Go to last line in Atom editor

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor, hotkeys

I wonder if there is a way to navigate to the last line of the file in atom editor given that you don't it's number(for instance you've just opened log file). Something similar to Shift + G in vim.

Comment: [CTRL] + [end] does not work? (in Linux and Win) Obviously [CTRL] + [home] to go back to the origin...

Comment: It could be that is's working on linux or windows, but I forgot to mention that I'm using mac. And neither Ctrl + home/end nor obviously  Command + home/end(fn + ↑/↓) works here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works the same as it does in every other macOS application:

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> jumps to last line (or <kbd>⇟</kbd> / <kbd>end</kbd> on a fullsize keyboard)
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> jumps to first line (or <kbd>⇞</kbd> / <kbd>home</kbd> on a fullsize keyboard)

If it still doesn't work, a third-party package might interfere. You can use the [`keybinding-resolver`](https://atom.io/packages/keybinding-resolver) (it's bundled with Atom) to find out which package causes this conflict.

Comment: Well, I was blind.

Answer (score 3):

- ubuntu 20.04
- atom 1.50.0
- ctrl + end to the file end
- ctrl + home to the file head

Answer (score 1):

Use ctrl+a to select all and then press ↑ to go to the top or ↓ to go to the bottom of the file. For the beginning / end of a line try ctrl-← and ctrl-→ or if it doesn't work try the same with shift or alt.

Comment: This works! And on the one side I like you way of navigation, because it's useful for any text editor on most of platforms (well, Command instead Ctrl for mac), on the other side this is more of a workaround, than a generic way, because it includes one unnecessary and potentially dangerous action.